# Global customs and trade import/export data on the shipping container level

Tags: data-request, economics, industry

I'm looking for global customs/trade data on the shipping container level that looks like the tables here: http://customstoday.com.pk/import-historical-customs-clearance-evidence-data-2014/

Pakistan has nicely formatted customs clearance data, but does any other country? And (fingers crossed), has anyone compiled this into an open source database?

Comment: Looks like the United States has a policy where the government cannot collect import data, but third party reporters can, and the government semi-endorses its sale. See [here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/319/kw/import%20data/session/L3RpbWUvMTQxODE4MjUzMi9zaWQvREkzeSp2OW0%3D/suggested/1).

Answer (score 6):

I'm clear you're looking for open data and NOT vendors, but I've found some of these vendors do give attribution to their sources and thus aid your search from their marketing materials:

- [Panjiva](http://www.panjiva.com)
- [Import Genius](http://www.importgenius.com)
- [Datamyne](http://%20www.datamyne.com)
- [Goodwill](http://www.goodwill.com.hk)
- [Fleetmon](http://www.fleetmon.com/en/vessels)
- [Marine Traffic](http://marinetraffic.org)
- [Vessel Finder](http://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels)
- [Container Ship](http://containership-info.com)
- [Maritime Connector](http://maritime-connector.com)
- [Marine Vessel Traffic](http://marinevesseltraffic.com)
- [Air Nav Systems](http://www.airnavsystems.com/ShipData/index.html)
- [CMA](http://www.cma-cgm.com/ebusiness/tracking)
- [Marine Vessel Traffic](http://www.marinevesseltraffic.com/2013/07/container-ships-and-cargo-tracking.html?m=1) (more)

Answer (score 4):

Data about imports and exports to the United States is available at several sources, but not necessarily at the shipping container level.  You can see:

- [U.S. international trade in goods and services](http://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/statistics/historical/) since 1960 from the U.S. Census (open data)

There are two sources referenced by @szxk earlier, which provide more detailed data, but are only free for the first 7 days of access:

- Detailed bills of lading for U.S. imports and exports via [PIERS](https://www.piers.com/MarketResearch) in this [format](https://www.piers.com/MarketResearch#bill1)
- Detailed ocean bills of lading for U.S. imports via [Ealing](http://www.iealing.com/tn/Query?list=consignee)